# JsonWebToken; JsonWebToken Error: JWT must be provided

Tags: node.js, reactjs, jwt, backend, web-development-server

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/acoVK.png)

My /login provides a jwt token to the session, which I am invalidating like this on /logout. But in doing so, /profile throws an error JsonWebToken; JsonWebToken Error: JWT must be provided.

How do I go about properly invalidating my token for logout functionality

Comment: JW token doesn't belong to cookies; it lives in the headers. `Authorization: Bearer <jwt>`.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `jwt.verify` with an empty string which gives the error `JsonWebToken; JsonWebToken Error: JWT must be provided.`. Instead check that a token actually exists before calling this function and provide an appropriate response. You could also wrap the call in a `try` block and send a response in the `catch` block.

Your logout functionality is also a little misguided. The whole point of a JWT is that it lives for a set time as defined by the `exp` claim. After expiration it is no longer valid, but cannot be invalidated until then. While the JWT exists you should accept it.

Many implementations of JWT also uses refresh tokens, which allow you to 'refresh your session' by obtaining a new JWT. The client might try to call your API with an expired token, API will respond appropriately (401 or similar) and the client will use the refresh token to get a new JWT. Logging out in this context usually means invalidating the refresh token.